# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha más reciente?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Intento realizar una consulta, que solo tome la fecha mas reciente de cada usuario, ya probé con operador `MAX` `SELECT NOMBRE,NUM,COLOR, MAX(SUBSTRING(FECPAGO,1,2)) FROM TABLA`, los valores de la tabla son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que deseo llegar es algo de este estilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cuál es el resultado que quieres obtener?, puedes postearlo?

Comment: Gracias @Lamak es algo de este estilo

Comment: NOMBRE NUM COLOR FECPAGO
JUAN 13 ROJO  15/03/2018
PABLO 13 BLANCO 15/02/2018
CARLOS  32 NEGRO 15/07/2018

Comment: Podes agregar como intentaste hacer el max? asi podemos corregirte en base a eso

Comment: y agrega esa informacion a la pregunta, usa el boton [edit] y agregalo ahi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acá te conviene usar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NOMBRE --o NUM, no sé cuál columna identifica al usuario
                              ORDER BY CONVERT(date,FECPAGO,103) DESC) RN
    FROM dbo.TuTabla
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

Como comentario extra, siempre que tengas fechas, trata de usar un tipo de dato que sea fecha, sino siempre tendrás que hacer conversiones y usar funciones rebuscadas para obtener el mes/año/día, etc.

Answer (score 1):

tendrás algunos problemas para realizar esa consulta ya que el campo  no es de tipo fecha, por lo que tendrás que desmenuzar esa cadena y volverla a armar para poderla manipular como un DATETIME.

A continuacion, te agrego un ejemplo ilustrativo que tendrías tu que realizar para hacer los ajustes a tu consulta.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd

IF EXISTS (SELECT
    ID
  FROM tempdb.sys.sysobjects
  WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Tabla')
  AND type = 'U')
  DROP TABLE #Tabla

CREATE TABLE #Tabla (
  NOMBRE varchar(30) NULL,
  NUM int NULL,
  COLOR varchar(20) NULL,
  FECPAGO varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Tabla VALUES ('JUAN', 25, 'ROJO', '14/03/2018')
INSERT INTO #Tabla VALUES ('JUAN', 13, 'ROJO', '15/03/2018')
INSERT INTO #Tabla VALUES ('PABLO', 25, 'BLANCO', '01/02/2018')
INSERT INTO #Tabla VALUES ('PABLO', 13, 'BLANCO', '15/02/2018')
INSERT INTO #Tabla VALUES ('CARLOS', 27, 'NEGRO', '01/07/2018')
INSERT INTO #Tabla VALUES ('CARLOS', 32, 'NEGRO', '15/07/2018')

SELECT
  NOMBRE,
  NUM,
  COLOR,
  FECPAGO
FROM (SELECT
  NOMBRE,
  NUM,
  COLOR,
  FECPAGO,
  UltimaFecha = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Nombre ORDER BY FecPago DESC)
FROM (SELECT
  NOMBRE,
  NUM,
  COLOR,
  FECPAGO = CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(FECPAGO, 7, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(FECPAGO, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(FECPAGO, 1, 2) + ' 00:00:00.000')
FROM #Tabla) tablaDerivada1) tablaDerivada2
WHERE UltimaFecha = 1
```

Nota: si tienes instalado SQL Server con una configuracion regional en ingles, puedes omitir esta linea `SET DATEFORMAT ymd`